# .htaccess location from folder inside localhost

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have an app could `system` and its inside http://localhost/folder1/system/app and want the .htaccess read it from app folder.

if i moved to localhost is working fine but if putting it to folder1 not working.

this is my current .htaccess status:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /system/app
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Try to find the `AllowOverride` commands in server configuration. And read about them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put your `.htaccess` file in `/folder1/system/app` then change
`RewriteBase /system/app` to `/folder1/system/app`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /folder1/system/app
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```